# MySQL inserting date

Tags: mysql, date, date-format

This is my MySQL Code:

```
UPDATE student SET birthDate = STR_TO_DATE(birthDate, '%M %d,%Y');

INSERT INTO student (`birthDate`) VALUES ('June 10,1997');
```

But it displays an error:

> Error code 1292, SQL state 22001: Data truncation: Incorrect date
>   value: 'June 10,1997' for column 'birthDate' at row 1

Comment: date is not stored in database in that format. it should be yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL uses a very specific date format, which is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

You can insert it as text once it's in that format (E.g no need for STR_TO_DATE).

Example: '1997-06-10'

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert a date into the column, use a proper date syntax:

```
INSERT INTO student (`birthDate`)
   VALUES ('1997-06-10');
```

Comment: yes, but i did Update the column format into this STR_TO_DATE(birthDate, '%M %d,%Y'), so can i insert or either alter the column into 'June 10,1997'?

Comment: @JustineP . . . You appear to be confused about something.  The `UPDATE` inserts a date value into the table.  It does not affect the format of the date stored in the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO student SET birthDate='1997-06-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

`STR_TO_DATE()` returns a properly formatted date based on the provided string and string format.

The following `INSERT` would work just fine

```
INSERT INTO student (`birthDate`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('June 10,1997', '%M %d,%Y'));
```

Because `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('June 10,1997', '%M %d,%Y')` returns `1997-06-10`

The update query you provided would not work if the birthDate field is a date field, because there is no way it could already contain a date in the format m d,Y (you are updating the column values in place)

If you had a column of dates in a varchar column (example, `birthDate_mdY`) in that format, then you could convert them to a date field like this

```
UPDATE student SET birthDate = STR_TO_DATE(birthDate_mdY, '%M %d,%Y')
```